# Dockerfile won't run script as user with sudo rights

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, docker

I have this Docker file...

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 MAINTAINER Sindhu S sindhu@alum.hackerschool.org
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install sudo wget bash git && rm -rf /var/cache/apt-get/archives/*
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" scrollback  
RUN adduser scrollback sudo  
RUN echo 'scrollback ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers RUN mkdir -p /home/scrollback && chown -R scrollback:scrollback /home/scrollback
WORKDIR /home/scrollback/ 
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sindhus/scrollback/install-script/tools/install.sh /home/scrollback/install.sh 
RUN chown scrollback:scrollback install.sh
RUN chmod +x install.sh
USER scrollback RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/home/scrollback/install.sh"]
```

As you can see its supposed to run the install.sh as scrollback user (this user has sudo rights). Basically the script shouldn't run as root but should run as user with sudo rights because there are some system files we need to modify.

I have tried with:

`RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"]`

and this works!

Yet when I have this line:

`RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/home/scrollback/install.sh"]`

in the script there is a line:

`$(sudo echo $apt_source > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list)`

and I get...

`Adding Postgres' deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main source to your software sources list (need root user rights)..
./install.sh: line 136: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list: Permission denied`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice using `sudo` inside a bash script. Instead use the command directly and run your script with `sudo`. Thus, your script (and the programs launched inside) will be launched with root privileges.